# android using firebase error getting the current user " Failed to get document because the client is offline"

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In my android app I try to re login an existing user, the UID is existing in the firebase, but I the `userTask.isSuccessful` is always `false`

my error that I get is:

> com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.

This is my code:

```
private FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
 private CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection(USERS);
 public MutableLiveData<User> addUserToLiveData(String uid) {
        MutableLiveData<User> userMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        usersRef.document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(userTask -> {
            if (userTask.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = userTask.getResult();
                if(document.exists()) {
                    User user = document.toObject(User.class);
                    userMutableLiveData.setValue(user);
                }
            } else {
                Exception s = userTask.getException();
                logErrorMessage(userTask.getException().getMessage());
            }
        });
        return userMutableLiveData;
    }
```

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: the document can't be loaded because the Firestore client can't reach its backend server, and it doesn't have the document available in its local cache. Are you sure the client has a network connection?

Comment: Are you sure the client is online?

Comment: Are you re logging in after immediate logging out? or is there an x amount of time that occurs before logging in again? Could this be related to firebase.auth() ?